# Can we use try catch in all sync or async function (NodeJS)?

Tags: node.js

Can we use try/catch in all sync or async functions in NodeJS or this may cause some issues ?

Comment: Of course you can. Do you have a specific issue with a specific piece of code?

Comment: No, it won't cause any errors.  And try to make a Google search if possible before posting questions here.

Comment: _Not_ using a try/catch in an async function when needed can end up with an unhandled rejection error down the line, though.

Comment: You can check out bluebird promises (documentation provided helps) :  http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.try.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try/catch` anywhere it's appropriate.  It will only catch some types of asynchronous errors.  For example, it won't catch an exception thrown in an plain asynchronous callback such as this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function getMyFile(name) {
    try {
        fs.readFile((err, data) => {
           if (err) throw err;
           console.log(data);
        });
    } catch(e) {
        // this won't catch the above thrown exception
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

The `try/catch` here won't catch the plain callback asynchronous exception because the function has already long since returned before the asynchronous callback is called and thus the `try/catch` is not able to catch it.

---

But, on the other hand, you absolutely use `try/catch` with `async/await` as it is the primary way that you catch rejected promises with an `await` statement:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

async function getMyFile(name) {
    try {
        let data = await fsp.readFile;
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        throw e;          // let returned promise stay rejected
    }
}
```